# ORA-02291 Integrity Constraint Error

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

I'm fairly new to SQL; I'm currently trying to populate my created tables with some sample data but whenever I do so it executes error message:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
INSERT INTO Customer (CustomerID, AccountID, CustomerType, CustomerStatus) 
VALUES (123485, 227482, 'Residential', 'Eligible')
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (T31833821.SYS_C0041532) violated - parent key not found
02291. 00000 - "integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - parent key not found"
*Cause:    A foreign key value has no matching primary key value.
*Action:   Delete the foreign key or add a matching primary key*.
```

Below is the code that I used to create my table of Customer (I've also created another table for AccountID, and they're currently both empty).

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
CustomerID NUMBER NOT NULL,
AccountID NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
CustomerType VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
CustomerStatus VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,    
CONSTRAINT customer_pk PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID),
CONSTRAINT check_customer_status CHECK(CustomerStatus IN ('Ineligible', 'Eligible')),
CONSTRAINT check_customer_type CHECK(CustomerType IN ('NonResident', 'Residential'))
);
```

I've attempted to establish foreign key and insert the sample data, but the aforementioned error kept appearing.

```
ALTER TABLE Customer ADD FOREIGN KEY (AccountID)
REFERENCES Account(AccountID);

INSERT INTO Customer (CustomerID, AccountID, CustomerType, CustomerStatus) 
VALUES (123485, 227482, 'nonresidential', 'eligible');
```

Anyway I could fix this? I'm using Oracle SQL

Comment: You don't have a row with `AccountID = 227482` in the `account` table.

Comment: Yeah I just realised that too, but the thing is that in the ACCOUNT table, the only attributes I have are AccountID (PK), AddressID and CustomerID (FK). So I can't populate that table too (Since customerID is also considered as descendant/child)

Comment: Your model is bad then. Remove the CustomerID FK from Account table. Also, I'm assuming you have an addresses table and AddressID defined as a FK there as well. You'll have the same problem there.

If you want to get lazy, not recommended, you can disable your fk constraints until you get things straightened out.

Comment: Yeah I agee, but I need an associative entity to distinguish customers with multiple accounts (under multiple addresses or property they own), which in this case I've used the ACCOUNT entity to associate them. Otherwise I'll just incorporate accountID into the same table (Customer), hope that'll work

I think i

Comment: You may wish to consider deferring the foreign key constraints so a customer and account can be both inserted before a commit is issued.

Comment: If a customer can have multiple accounts, then you don't need an account id on the customer table. Remove CUSTOMER.ACCOUNTID from the table and from your insert statement (this will also solve your integrity constraint violation). ACCOUNT.CUSTOMERID should be a foreign key referencing CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID. This will give you the one (customer) to many (accounts) relation you're trying to implement.

Comment: In addition to the identified error you listed, your `CustomerType` column should probably be a  VARCHAR2(20) in lieu of VARCHAR(10).  You will never, ever fit 'nonresidential' into VARCHAR(10).

Comment: @bacs - your comment is the answer to this question.  You should post it as one.

Comment: You also have a problem with your check constraint: the value that you insert: `'eligible'` is different from the value in the check constraint: `'Eligible'` - String comparison is case-sensitive.